# Как сделать чтобы в haskell корректно выводились числа double?

Tags: haskell

Если я сделаю код
`show 8.0` оно выведет `8.0`
а мне надо чтобы выводило 8 но если `show 5.5` то выводило 5.5, Простите заранее что такая плохая формулировка, я не знаю как это сказать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Определите собственную функцию преобразования числа в строку, рассматривайте целочисленные значения как отдельный случай

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}

showDouble :: Double -> String
showDouble (properFraction -> (x, 0)) = show x
showDouble x = show x
```

Или если без расширений

```hs
showDouble :: Double -> String
showDouble x | (x', 0) <- properFraction x = show x'
showDouble x = show x
```

```hs
GHCi> showDouble 8.0
"8"
GHCi> showDouble 5.5
"5.5"
```